# How do I reference or access my classes from a bundle created by webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/) to learn webpack. It's out-dated, since the tools referenced are upgraded in my case. My versions are as follows.

- ts-loader ^1.3.3
- tsd ^0.6.5
- typescript ^2.1.5
- webpack ^1.14.0

After successfully creating a `bundle.js` file, I seem to be having problems accessing/referencing my TypeScript to JavaScript classes. My `tsconfig.json` looks like the following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My wepack.config.js looks like the following.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {  
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

To transpile the TypeScript code, I simply type in `tsc`. To bundle all the code into `bundle.js`, I simply type in `webpack`. (tsc and webpack are installed globally).

In my src directory, I only have 2 simple classes. The `car.ts` looks like the following.

```
export class Car {
  public sayHi(): void {
    console.log('car says hi');
  }
}
```

The `app.ts` looks like the following.

```
import { Car } from './car'; //alternatively, import Car = require('./car');

let car = new Car();
car.sayHi();
```

I then load this `bundle.js` into a browser in a HTML page as follows.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see in the (Chrome) JavaScript console the log message "car says hi". But how do I create a new instance of Car? The following attempts at the JavaScript console doesn't work.

```
var c1 = new Car(); //Uncaught reference error
var c2 = new car.Car(); //Uncaught reference error
```

Inside `bundle.js`, I do see this code/modules being generated (snippet).

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";
    var car_1 = __webpack_require__(1);
    var car = new car_1.Car();
    car.sayHi();


/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";
    var Car = (function () {
        function Car() {
        }
        Car.prototype.sayHi = function () {
            console.log('car says hi');
        };
        return Car;
    }());
    exports.Car = Car;


/***/ }
```

My end goal is to get all TypeScript files in the `src` directory transpiled with (TypeScript) mappings into a single `bundle.js` as a module so I can use/reference the code (as JavaScript in a browser) as follows.

```
var car = new mylib.Car();
var plane = new mylib.Plane();
car.sayHi();
plane.sayHi();
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you solve your problem? Can you share it with me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `output.library` setting:

```
output: {
    ...
    library: 'MyLibrary'
}
```

Then you can use it this way in the console:

```
var x = new MyLibrary.Car();
```

[Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) (output.libray)

[Similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013554/accessing-webpack-bundled-libraries-in-the-browser#answers)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is let webPack handle the transpilation for you as well.
Using a [TypeScript loader](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).

What webpack does is making modules (this last file you put, everything is inside a function with context and without the Name you gave on a global space).Any global names are bound to the scope (or changed if you ugligy) so You can't access them from the console. Make webpack use the typescript loader and you can reference the car simply requiring or importing the file.

Comment: If you look at my webpack.config.js, don't I specify the `ts-loader`?

Comment: Since you referenced the official docs, I swapped out `ts-loader` with `awesome-typescript-loader` and I still get the same effect. No difference. I can't reference the class.

Comment: But are you still trying to reference then from console? Also I may misinterpreted but I was under the impression that you were compiling the ts manually and then bundling

Comment: From the top of my head if you want to play it with the console like you did on the text , perhaps you could add Car to the global space as "window.Car = Car"

Comment: No, I am simply typing `webpack` to generate `bundle.js` (ignore the `tsc` part). I am not trying to reference the classes from the console (e.g. nodejs) but from the browser. No, I don't want to pollute the global name space like that. Like I said, `mylib.Car` is preferred.

Comment: I meant browser console not terminal console. Webpack will isolate your bundle so if you want to access it from browser console you need to put it on global namespace